# Creating multipage tif in Freeimagepy, memory not being freed

Tags: python, image, tiff

I have created a program to merge TIFs into multipage tifs with an rather old version of FreeImagePy from 2009.  It actually works pretty well but I have one little hitch.  As best I can tell it's not freeing up the memory and eventually crashes.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Using Ptyhon 2.7.

```
import urllib
import FreeImagePy as FIPY
import os.path
import time

# set source files
sourceFile = open('C:\\temp\AGetStatePlats\\PlatsGenesee.csv','r')
# logfile currently gets totally replaced at each run
logFile = open('C:\\temp\\AGetStatePlats\\PlatTifMerge.txt','w')
sourcePath = "c:\\temp\subdownload2\\"
destPath = 'C:\\temp\\subtifMerge\\'

for row in sourceFile:
        # prepare filenames
        subPath = row.split(',',1)[0]
        platID = subPath.split('/',1)[1]
        curDocument = sourcePath + platID + '01.tif'
        curPage = 0
        # check if base file is out there
        if not os.path.isfile(destPath + platID + '.tif'):
                outImage = FIPY.Image()
                outImage.new(multiBitmap = destPath + platID +'.tif')
                print (destPath + platID +'.tif')
                for n in range (1,100):
                        #build n
                        nPad = "{:0>2}".format(n)
                        if os.path.isfile(sourcePath + platID + nPad + '.tif'):
                              # delay in case file system is not keeping up may not be needed  
                              time.sleep (1.0/4.0)  
                              outImage.appendPage(sourcePath + platID + nPad + '.tif')
                              curPage = curPage + 1
                        else:
                              outImage.deletePage(0)          
                              outImage.close()
                              del outImage
                              logFile.write(sourcePath + platID + '.tif' + '\r')
                              logFile.write(platID + " PageCount = " + str(curPage) + '\r' )
                              break
        else:
                logFile.write(platID + " already exists" + '\r')
# cleanup

sourceFile.close()
logFile.close()

print("Run Complete!")
```

Here's the error messages:

C:\temp\subtifMerge\05848.tif ('Error returned. ', 'TIFF', 'Warning: parsing error. Image may be incomplete or contain invalid data !') Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\temp\AGetStatePlats\PlatTIFcombine.py", line 43, in  outImage.appendPage(sourcePath + platID + nPad + '.tif') File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\FreeImagePy\FreeIm??agePy.py", line 2048, in appendPage bitmap = self.genericLoader(fileName) File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\FreeImagePy\FreeIm??agePy.py", line 1494, in genericLoader dib = self.Load(fif, fileName, flag); File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\FreeImagePy\FreeIm??agePy.py", line 188, in Load return self.__lib.Load(typ, fileName, flags)

WindowsError: exception: priviledged instruction >>>

Comment: Why don't you think it's freeing memory? It sounds like you keep adding things to memory by asking it to hold more and more pages in memory.

Comment: When i run the program it processes say a fair number of files then crashes.  the number of files it processes varies and seems related to their size.  I watch the windows memory usage and it gradually increases until about the same point where it crashes.     According to the API document   .close should "close" the loaded bitmap and del() should "unload" the bit map.    I tried forcing garbage collection with gc.collect() but that seems to have no effect.

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: It's illegible in the comments. Please edit it into your question.